# SO Jobs - Pagination page links are offset

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, pagination

I was looking on the SO Jobs page and I noticed that the pagination is slightly offset.

This link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=php&location=london&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles+&rs=1 refers to page 1 of searching for PHP jobs in London. I scrolled down to find this at the links:

[image]

I initially thought I had mysteriosuly clicked onto page 2 without remembering, until I clicked onto page 2 to be presented with:

[image]

Realising that I had found a potential bug, I dug a little deeper, and it appears to be the whole Jobs section of SO.

[image]

Comment: Good spot, I was refactoring some bits and missed an off-by-one. Fixing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I made some changes yesterday to eliminate some unnecessary queries to Elastic search for suggestions. Sadly that surfaced an off-by-one bug in an alternate code path that, apparently, never got noticed.

It's fixed now!